# VBA - Separate only by the second "-" into another column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to have a code that separate a string by the second "-".  Example :
 1. What I have is A1 : 12345-6789-Name
 2. What I want is A1: 12345-6789 & B1: -Name

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub MySplit()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
        Dim str() As String
        str = Split(.Range("A1"), "-")
        If UBound(str) > 1 Then
            .Range("A1").Value = str(0) & "-" & str(1)
            .Range("B1").Value = "-" & str(2)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```